# Helm: It is possible to use nindent function with template function?

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, indentation

I'm a bit new to helm syntax and I'm trying to include a template in my deployments file. In some of my deployments the indent must be different. Is there a way to include my template and use indent function as well?

```
{{ template "my-chart.nodeaffinity" include "my-chart.fullname" . | toYaml | nindent 8 }}
```

It is possible to use the **template** and **toYaml** function in the same statement?

Thanks!

I have tried to add the bellow code but is not working and when I use helm template the nindent function is not working.

```
| toYaml | nindent 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use `template` and `toYaml` together as you describe.  What you can do is use the similar but Helm-specific [`include`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#the-include-function) function in place of `template`:

```
{{ include "my-chart.nodeaffinity" (include "my-chart.fullname" .) | toYaml | nindent 8 }}
{{/*^^^^^^ not template            ^---    need parens here   ---^                    */}}
```

`template` is a built-in Go `text/template` action.  It consumes the pipeline in the rest of its block, and it always sends its output to the rendered template output.  So `{{ template "name" "arg" | toYaml }}` reads `"arg" | toYaml` as the *parameter* to the template, and there's no way to process its output.

`include` is an extension function in the template syntax.  It renders a template in the same way `template` does, but it returns the rendered string, which can then participate in pipelines.  So `{{ include "name" "arg" | toYaml }}` calls the template with exactly the specified argument, and then processes the return value.

One corollary to this is that **`include` always returns a string**.  Even if it looks like the helper template is producing a YAML object, it's really a string.  This might mean you don't want `toYaml` here, since it could cause extra escaping you don't need.

You can see a more concrete example of this in the [default chart scaffolding](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/main/pkg/chartutil/create.go).  A standard set of labels is defined as a template

```yaml
{{- define "<CHARTNAME>.labels" -}}
helm.sh/chart: {{ include "<CHARTNAME>.chart" . }}
...
{{- end }}
```

When this is used, it's used via `include` (not `template`), and its output is (`n`)`indent`ed

```yaml
metadata:
  labels:
    {{- include "<CHARTNAME>.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining the behavior of template and include, it is more clear to me, and this solution worked as well!

Thanks!!!